# Automatically install a project in the local repository?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'm trying to work around a maven bug MDEP-187 ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-187 ) by not using workspace resolution.

This forces me to do a mvn install for all my dependencies, I'm doing this by creating a launch configuration in eclipse with goal install.

The problem is that i have to create a launch config for every project in my multiproject workspace, in addition to install i have to manually call every launch config and run it. Which just doesn't work.

Is it possible to automatically install a project in the local repository? (whenever i update my code)

Comment: @dur copy-dependencies is not really needed for every build in eclipse, being a bit spoiled by eclipse "always build everything". I can simply create a bat file that calls mvn:install on my root (which installs everything in my local rep) and finally do a mvn call on a project to create the runnable jar all dependencies in a separate directory. I'm currently trying to get a standalone maven running and see if this is going to work.

Comment: @khmarbaise the bug causes copy dependence to fail on multi module project when using workspace resolution, when you do mvn install to install all dependencies in local rep then workspace resolution isn't needed anymore, cause maven just finds the dependencies in local rep. Working around the bug. Although i'm now bumping into problem with dependency on non maven project, which would have worked with workspace resolution on.

Comment: @khmarbaise my apolgies, still a bit new when it comes to maven internals, but i'm using maven-dependency-plugin "copy-dependencies" to copy dependencies of a java application to a directory (/lib/). This is useful for running the application without putting all dependencies in the main jar.

Comment: @khmarbaise as we speak just a normal java application with swing ui.

Comment: But than you need to can handle the whole thing via [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) which can create archives / folders with all the dependencies. Apart from that a swing ui must be started somehow which will need some kind of shell script / batch file which you can create by using [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/)...And it sounds like you need to go for a multi module project in maven..cause you might have parts like core, ui, etc. which are needed to be combined in the end.

Comment: @khmarbaise i was in the understanding that the assembly-plugin didn't support putting dependencies in a lib/ folder (just putting everything in 1 big jar), but after a little bit of trying i just go myself a zip with a runnable jar and my dependencies in a lib/ folder. Tomorrow i'm going to read a bit more about the assembly-plugin. I'm happy ;-)

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/assembly-howto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did go with @khmarbaise solution:

> But than you need to can handle the whole thing via
>   maven-assembly-plugin which can create archives / folders with all the
>   dependencies. Apart from that a swing ui must be started somehow which
>   will need some kind of shell script / batch file which you can create
>   by using appassembler-maven-plugin...And it sounds like you need to go
>   for a multi module project in maven..cause you might have parts like
>   core, ui, etc. which are needed to be combined in the end.
>
> @khmarbaise i was in the understanding that the assembly-plugin didn't
>   support putting dependencies in a lib/ folder (just putting everything
>   in 1 big jar), but after a little bit of trying i just go myself a zip
>   with a runnable jar and my dependencies in a lib/ folder. Tomorrow i'm
>   going to read a bit more about the assembly-plugin. I'm happy ;-

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to run `dependency:copy` in Eclipse, you can use following work-around:

- Add a [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to your `pom.xml`, something like this:

  ```
  <profiles>
      <profile>
          <id>copy</id>
          <build>
              <plugins>
                  <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                      <version>2.10</version>
                      <executions>
                          [...]
                      </executions>
                  </plugin>
              </plugins> 
          <build>
      <profile>
  </profiles>
  ```
- Enable workspace resolution in Eclipse.

Then Eclipse will not use `dependency:copy`, but you can use `dependency:copy` with command line: `mvn install -P copy`.